# 'application/pdf' blob in safari iframe does not display, but the blob url works in a separate tab within safari

Tags: pdf, iframe, safari

It works on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, but not in safari. In Safari the iframe looks like it knows it should display a pdf (grey background) but with no pages inside it.

```
const pdf = new Blob([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)], { type: 'application/pdf' })
setDataStreamURL(window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf))
...
<iframe title={iframeTitle} className={className} src={dataStreamURL} type={type} />
```

It does work fine if I give it an url to a pdf like this one:

https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

but I need to give it the `blob:...` url created by `window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf)`

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late in answering this but I faced this same issue while previewing a PDF from a blob url using an iframe on Safari. `FileReader` did the trick for me. From your code, instead of using `window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf)`, read the blob which is here is pdf through a `FileReader` as shown bellow:

```js
const pdf = new Blob([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)], { type: 'application/pdf' })

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = () => {
const url = reader.result; // Use this `url` in iframe src
};

reader.readAsDataURL(pdf);
```

**Note** that this trick worked in Safari but might not work in other browsers, so use the blob url for other browsers and this trick for Safari.